# Rendering a template to string in rust rocket

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I'm writing a small website in rust rocket. I'm using handlebar templates, and the way you return a `Template` form a handler is quite convenient. But I also want to use my template engine for emails I'm sending out. The problem is, that Templates in `rocket_contrib` do not really support rendering to a `String`.

There is a method [`show()`](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.3/rocket_contrib/struct.Template.html#method.show), that creates `Option<String>`, but that one is not supposed to be used.

> Render the template named name located at the path root with the context context into a String. This method is very slow and should not be used in any running Rocket application. This method should only be used during testing to validate Template responses. For other uses, use `render` instead.

The method [`render()`](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.3/rocket_contrib/struct.Template.html#method.render) is what you normally use, but this one returns a `Template`, which is what I started with... You return those and rocket does its magic to produce the resulting html-page.

Is there any way to use my templates in rocket for emails? My mailer (lettre) expects a String.

Comment: You can directly use [handlebars](https://github.com/sunng87/handlebars-rust#quick-start) to render the template instead of relying on rocket for email templates

Comment: While that is true, I do have an infrastructure built up in rust that finds my templates in the file system and has my helpers installed. I would have to put that up again in parallel. I would like not to have to do that.

Comment: I have this same question.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly fine to use `show()`. Here is [how it's implemented](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/src/rocket_contrib/templates/mod.rs.html#345) in `Rocket`:

```rust
    pub fn show<S, C>(rocket: &Rocket, name: S, context: C) -> Option<String>
        where S: Into<Cow<'static, str>>, C: Serialize
    {
        let ctxt = rocket.state::<ContextManager>().map(ContextManager::context).or_else(|| {
            // N.B.: removed some logging for brevity
            None
        })?;

        Template::render(name, context).finalize(&ctxt).ok().map(|v| v.0)
    }
```

As you can see `show()` **does** call `render()` internally, just as the rustdoc told us to do instead. But here it also calls `finalize()`. Let's check [what does it do](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/src/rocket_contrib/templates/mod.rs.html#362):

```
/// Actually render this template given a template context. This method is
/// called by the `Template` `Responder` implementation as well as
/// `Template::show()`.
```

Ok, so `render()` does not really render anything. It's `finalize()` that's doing the job.

We can also check [how the `Responder` is implemented](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/src/rocket_contrib/templates/mod.rs.html#386):

```rust
/// Returns a response with the Content-Type derived from the template's
/// extension and a fixed-size body containing the rendered template. If
/// rendering fails, an `Err` of `Status::InternalServerError` is returned.
impl Responder<'static> for Template {
    fn respond_to(self, req: &Request) -> response::Result<'static> {
        let ctxt = req.guard::<State<ContextManager>>().succeeded().ok_or_else(|| {
            // N.B.: removed some logging for brevity
            Status::InternalServerError
        })?.inner().context();

        let (render, content_type) = self.finalize(&ctxt)?;
        Content(content_type, render).respond_to(req)
    }
}
```

**TL;DR:** It seems that the documentation is misleading. The template implementation is doing absolutely the same thing when you call `show()` and when you send a response. In both cases it invokes `finalize()` internally, which produces the `String` rendering of the template. Thus there should not be any performance penalty of using `show()`

PS: The code in the [current `main` branch](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/blob/8cae077ba1d54b92cdef3e171a730b819d5eeb8e/contrib/dyn_templates/src/lib.rs#L387) has changed a bit, but the logic is still the same

Comment: One question (I am still pretty new to rust), if the `show` function is called in one of the routes, but requires `rocket` as an argument, how does it get that in scope if the rocket is in the `main` function?